# bash file with multiple commands

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Hello I'm trying to create a bash file that will do the following:

1. open a new terminal window
2. execute number of commands in that new terminal window.

My bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal.app -e sudo sh -c cd ~ && cd .. && cd .. && cd to the directory that I want && ./someExecutable
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: @music2myear nothing happen

Comment: why not just use the directory you want in the command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes to your multi-word `-c` argument. Otherwise only the first word is seen as an argument of `-c`.  The same for `-e` using different quotes to avoid ambiguity.

Example:

```
...  -e 'sudo sh -c "cd ~ && cd .. && cd .. && ..... && ./yourExecutable"'
```